# AdSense won't render on some URLs

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

I have a website with standard design, basically same on all pages except for main content part.

Now, I have two types of posts and source code behind it is the same except for some validations, but first post type has 2 url segments, and second has 3 url segments.

I'm using DFP to serve ads, and on pages with 3 segments, AdSense ads won't show up. Other custom ads show up with no problem, and AdSense ads show up fine on all other pages.

Also DFP seems to render ad slot, but it just comes up empty.

My website is written in Laravel 4 (but it probably doesn't matter)

Any idea why won't adsense render?

Comment: May be cross domain issue like HTTP and HTTPS issue , somewhere url calling withh SSL and somewhere non-SSL

Comment: Check if the console of your browser is telling you that errors occur, it could help to find what the issue is

Comment: Also check the DFP console https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/181070?hl=en

Comment: It's all HTTP, and console sad nothing. One thing i have found out. If my url is `/segment1/segment2/segment3` and adSense don't render, I can modify url to `/segment1/segment2/segment3?anything` and it will work fine.

Comment: Also, when i use `?google_force_console` everything is loaded normally. I have some ad slots that don't appear on some pages, but that is the case with all of pages. Thoes who render fine, and those with bug

Comment: Apparently, AdSense ads won't render if page url ends with letter "a", as strange as it may sound

Comment: @VukBG, how did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that some pages do not have enough content and google can not determine the topic in order to show ads.

In your ads settings find: "Backup ads". And check "Fill space with solid color". In this case if google does not have to show any ads you will see the chosen color in your ads.

Comment: this was the problem. I find that out back when I posted the question, but forgot to answer it. Thanks :)